# Save Nemo tabs in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, nemo

Is it possible to always load a specific set of file browser (Nemo) tabs in Linux Mint? I would like to have five folder locations opened by default every time I start Nemo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is very much possible. I use a python script for this task for my `caja` browser. I am reproducing the script here by replacing `caja` with `nemo`. Hopefully, it will directly work with `nemo` without any further changes.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8")
def run(cmd):
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])

try:
    arg = sys.argv[1]
except:
    arg = ""

try:
    pid = get("pidof nemo").strip()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    run("nemo "+arg)
else:
    w = [l.split() for l in get("wmctrl -lp").splitlines() if pid in l][-1]
    w_id = w[0]   
    if len( [l for l in get("xprop -id "+w_id).splitlines() if all(
        ["_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM)" in l, "_TYPE_NORMAL" in l])]) != 0:
        run("wmctrl -ia "+w[0])
        run("xdotool key Control_L+t")
        if arg != "":
            run("xdotool key Control_L+l")
            time.sleep(0.2)
            run("xdotool type "+arg)
            time.sleep(0.01*len(arg))
            run("xdotool key Return")
    else:
        run("nemo "+arg)
```

Save this script as `nemo-tab.py` in your `~/bin` directory or any other directory which you have in your path. Make it executable. Then, when you run this script it will open up a new tab in any current running `nemo` browser or start a new browser if no instance is running. You run it as following:

```
nemo-tab.py "~/Documents"
```

Now, for your case, you can issue the command five times in a bash script to load a `nemo` instance with 5 initial tabs:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
nemo-tab.py "~/Documents"
nemo-tab.py "~/Desktop"
nemo-tab.py "~/media/data"
nemo-tab.py "~/Videos"
nemo-tab.py "~/Pictures"
```

Note that you will need to install `xdotool` and `wmctrl`:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
```

Source of Python script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/628084/what-is-the-command-to-open-a-specific-directory-in-a-new-tab-in-nautilus

Answer (score -1):

Add this to terminal or shortcut:

```
nemo -t recent:/// Downloads trash:///
```

type "nemo -h" in terminal for more options.

If you create a desktop shortcut be sure to set the "working directory" /home/(name)

Tested on Manjaro-xfce.