# Trying To Make Nemo File Manager Remember A Specific Group Of Tabs And Open Them On Nemo Launch

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon, nemo

i followed the below link tutorial as follows and had no luck getting nemo to remember a group of tabs "opened bin as root, created the above nemo-tab.py.,made it executable, installed xdotool and wmctrl, and beyond that i'm at a loss. thought rightclicking on bin, open in terminal, and entering nemo-tab.py "/home/mc2635599/Desktop/Shortcuts" would do the trick, but all it did was open a copy of the tab i already had open. once i did the 4th tab i wanted i exited terminal, closed nemo, relaunched nemo and no multiple tabs."

[Save Nemo tabs in Linux Mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238347/save-nemo-tabs-in-linux-mint/490480#490480)

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the answer you linked to. The python script doesn't remember anything. You have to feed it all the tabs you wish to open, in a wrapper script.

So - take a note of the open tabs you wish to "save".
create a script as per the example (Don't forget to replace the paths with the ones you noted first):

```
#!/bin/bash
nemo-tab.py "~/Documents"
nemo-tab.py "~/Desktop"
nemo-tab.py "~/media/data"
nemo-tab.py "~/Videos"
nemo-tab.py "~/Pictures"
```

And launch that script instead of launching nemo directly.

Comment: "And launch that script instead of launching nemo directly.". so do what i did and once created click on the nemo-tab.py? then i can send that to the desktop or create a shortcut wherever i want it?

Comment: No, nemo-tab.py is not the wrapper script. The wrapper script has `nemo-tab.py "/some/path"` lines in it. You create a wrapper script which calls nemo-tab.py several times, each time with a different argument, and launch THE WRAPPER SCRIPT instead of nemo or nemo-tab.py.

Comment: You create the wrapper script yourself, based on your personal preference and requirements

Comment: Please read the tutorial and my answer more carefully- create a script appears in both

Comment: ok took me a minute but that #/bin/bash is a text file like the .py file is and i just save that as a script file, right? so....                                                   
                                                                                                            
#!/bin/bash
nemo-tab.py "/home/mc2635599/Desktop"
nemo-tab.py "/home/mc2635599/Desktop/Shortcuts"
nemo-tab.py "home/CombinedPartitions/Downloads/Torrents"
nemo-tab.py "home/CombinedPartitions/TV Series"
nemo-tab.py "home/ComBinedPartitions/TV Series/Last Night's"